# Set descrption for subscription renewal payment on stripe

Tags: php, payment

I am able to set the subscription plan successfully but now i description(message) for those who have renewed under this subscription plan. for this i need to set the description(any custom message) for this. How can i achieve this. Please help me on this.

Comment: It is really difficult to guess what you are asking. Please add more details to your question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation on stripe for charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_charge) states:

> description **optional**, *default is null* 
>   An arbitrary string which you
>   can attach to a charge object. It is displayed when in the web
>   interface alongside the charge. Note that if you use Stripe to send
>   automatic email receipts to your customers, your receipt emails will
>   include the description of the charge(s) that they are describing.

For [a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_plan) you need to set `statement_description`.

Example usages are also listed on the site.

Comment: Thanks andy. Correct I understand it. finally its an charge object only. I need to set the description for subscription plan object. How i can do this

Comment: A plan also has a `statement_description`. A subscription will use that description for charges from that plan. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I want to generate the reports based on the subscription description on stripe end. How i can do this?